Aligning the audio from a file to the video of another with MKVToolNix
I sometimes have to use the French audio from a video file to insert it into another video in English, and I use MKVToolNix for this (with MKVToolNixGUI).
I know how to add a delay, and even how to stretch the video if it's not the same length as the other (I take the time of one event at the beginning and another at the end of each video, and put the results in seconds as a fraction in the ‘Stretch by:’ input field), but sometimes, if the sound is correctly adjusted at the beginning, it's not at the end.
Is there anything I don't know to help me achieve the right result, or is there a better programme for performing this operation?
I looked on this forum and found advice about Shutter Encoder, but it seems a bit complicated for me, I cannot have the wanted result, and I'd rather use MKVToolNixGUI that I know better if possible.
